# Post back Method not get call on button click in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have created a login page without _layout.cshtml in mvc4 and added two text box with a button. But when i click button it no getting post back. I have tried using breakpoint. pls help. My Code

```
@model MapProjectMVC.Models.LoginModel

@{
   Layout = null;    
 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Special Spots</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="loginBox">
      <div class="loginHead">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Special Spots -  responsive admin panel" title="Special Spots -  responsive admin panel" />
     </div>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">
            User Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">
            Password</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">
            Sign in</button>
    </div>
</div>
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")   
</body>
</html>


 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel LM)
    {           
        var UserId = new ObjectParameter("userId",typeof(string));
        var res = new ObjectParameter("res",typeof(Int32));
        int i = ssc.ValidateAdminLogin(LM.UserName, LM.Password, UserId, res);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(res) == 1)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
        }

        return View(LM);
    }
```

Comment: @EhsanSajjad as i have created another page with default _layout.cshtml there is no need to add form. So clear me why to add form tag in this page.

Comment: In asp.net mvc whenever we need to post values we have to use form

Comment: I have used form it working now thanks for your help. As above code i used object parameter, i want to convert that in int, how to do it.

Comment: You have `Layout = null;` so your not using a layout! (not that it would make any difference anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the input elements and submit button in form. For this purpose you can use asp.net mvc Html Helper Extension for form  `Html.BeginForm()` this way:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 <div class="loginBox">
      <div class="loginHead">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Special Spots -  responsive admin panel" title="Special Spots -  responsive admin panel" />
     </div>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">
            User Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">
            Password</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">
            Sign in</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

There are many overloads of `Html.BeginForm()`,  [**See all overloads here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)